# JSTL - How can I pass values to SQL statement

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, jsp, jstl

```
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
 url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample"
 user="app"  password="app"/>

<sql:update dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
    insert into stock_tbl values ('?','?')
<sql:param value="${symb}" />
<sql:param value="${nm}" />
</sql:update>
```

When I run this in the web browser I am receiving an error.

```
type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: 
insert into stock_tbl values ('?','?')


: UNKNOWN MESSAGE, id 07009 : 
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: UNKNOWN MESSAGE, id 07009 : 
root cause

org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: UNKNOWN MESSAGE, id 07009 :
```

The HTML File
[HTML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/catgZ.png)

Comment: I admit that I'm guessing but I doubt you need quotes around the `?` parameter markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the quotes from `insert into stock_tbl values ('?','?')`. the 2 `?` are being interpreted as values not placeholders.

here's an example 
http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/jstl/jstl-sql-tag-param